# Analytic continuation of a holomorphic function bounded on neighbourhood of 'small' compact subset $K\subset\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

I have two questions regarding the following exercise. First, is my solution (see below) correct? Second, how would the solution go that the writer of the book had in mind (i.e. using the hint)?

> Let $K\subset\mathbb{C}$ be a compact set such that $\mathbb{C}-K$ is connected and such that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exist balls with $K\subset\bigcup_jB(a_j,r_j)$ and $\sum_jr_j<\epsilon$; you may assume (for this exercise) that the balls can be chosen disjoint for every $\epsilon>0$. Let $U\supset K$ be open. Proof that every holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}-K$, bounded on $U-K$ can be analytically continued to $\mathbb{C}$.

It is given as a hint to use Cauchy's theorem, but I had no clue how Cauchy's theorem is of any help here; I came up with a solution myself.

So take an $a\in K$, then for every $\epsilon>0$ we can find an $\alpha_{\epsilon}\in K$ and an $0<r_{\epsilon}<\epsilon$ such that $a\in B(\alpha_{\epsilon},r_{\epsilon})$; choosing the balls disjoint we could find $\delta\in(0,\epsilon)$ such that $A(\alpha_{\epsilon},r_{\epsilon}+\frac{\delta_{\epsilon}}{2},r_{\epsilon}+\delta_{\epsilon})\subset\mathbb{C}-K$. Now let's choose $\epsilon$ small enough such that the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $K$ is contained in $U$; than by the boundedness property there exists an $M$ such that for any such $\epsilon$ $f$ is bounded by this $M$ on $A(\alpha_{\epsilon},r_{\epsilon}+\frac{\delta_{\epsilon}}{2},r_{\epsilon}+\delta_{\epsilon})$. But if $\epsilon\to0,r_{\epsilon}\to0$ and $\alpha_{\epsilon}\to a$. Now take a sequence $(\epsilon_ n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converging to $0$, then we can for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ freely choose a $\beta_n\in A(\alpha_{\epsilon_n},r_{\epsilon_n}+\frac{\delta_{\epsilon_n}}{2},r_{\epsilon_n}+\delta_{\epsilon_n})$, and by boundedness we would have $\lim_{n\to\infty}(z-a)f(\beta_n)=0$; because this is true for any such sequence
$(\epsilon_ n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converging to $0$ and any choice for the $\beta_n$'s, we have $\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)f(z)=0$. Thus $f$ has a removable singularity in $a$. The $a\in K$ was arbitrary; for any such $a$ we remove the singularity; we get an analytic continuation $\tilde{f}$ on $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: It is not clear to me why a generic compact set should admit a covering by pairwise disjoint discs.

Can you cover the segment $0 \leq x \leq 1$ on the real line in $\mathbb{C}$ with pairwise disjoint discs of radius $10^{-1}$?

Comment: @avs: agreed, but the exercise allows us to make this assumption. If you could think of a solution not making this assumption, that would be even better of course!

Comment: Do you realize that your assumption implies that $K$ is a finite set of points?

Comment: @avs: why is that? Can't $K$ be (for example) $\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ under the assumptions made?

Comment: The set you formed is not compact (because not closed).  However, you are right, it can be covered by finitely many discs of arbitrarily small radius.

Comment: @avs, yes I just figured out it is not even closed... Thanks. But why does it have to be a finite point set? I still don't see

Comment: It doesn't, I was incorrect.  If we take your set and insert $0$, we obtain a compact set, which admits such a covering.  However, the assumption implies that all the points of that set must be isolated (i.e., each has a neighborhood containing no other points).

Otherwise, if a set contains as much as a tiny linear segment, it can't be so covered.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First note $((z-1)(z+1))^{1/2}$ is analytic on $\Bbb{C}- [-1,1]$, it is bounded on $|z| \le 2$, but it is not analytic on $\Bbb{C}$. So $K = [-1,1]$ doesn't work.
- If $f$ is analytic on $\Bbb{C} - K$ then for any curve $\gamma$ enclosing $K$ counter clockwise and $K \subset B_0(r)$ and $|z| < R, z \not \in K$ $$f(z) = \frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{|z|= R} \frac{f(s)}{s-z}ds - \frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_\gamma \frac{f(s)}{s-z}ds$$
- Your assumption is that $K \subset B_0(R)$, $\sup_{|z| \le R} |f(z)| \le C$ and for every $\epsilon$, there are $a_{j,\epsilon},r_{j,\epsilon}$ such that  $K \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^{J_\epsilon} B(a_{j,\epsilon},r_{j,\epsilon})$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{J_\epsilon} r_{j,\epsilon} < \epsilon$.

  Thus $\gamma_\epsilon = \bigcup_{j=1}^{J_\epsilon} \partial B(a_{j,\epsilon},r_{j,\epsilon})$ encloses $K$ and  $$| \int_{\gamma_\epsilon} \frac{f(s)}{s-z}ds| =
     |\sum_{j=1}^{J_\epsilon} \int_{\partial B(a_{j,\epsilon},r_{j,\epsilon})}\frac{f(s)}{s-z}ds| \le \sum_{j=1}^{J_\epsilon}C 2\pi r_{j,\epsilon} \le C2\pi \epsilon $$ Whence $\int_\gamma \frac{f(s)}{s-z}ds =\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\gamma_\epsilon} \frac{f(s)}{s-z}ds= 0$ ie. $$f(z) = \frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{|z|= R} \frac{f(s)}{s-z}ds = \frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{|z|= R} \frac{f(s)}{s}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (z/s)^k ds=\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k \frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{|z|= R} \frac{f(s)}{s^{k+1}}ds$$ is analytic and entire.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! One question: what do you mean with your first comment? It seems that there do not exist balls with $K\subset\bigcup_jB(a_j,r_j)$ and $\sum_jr_j<\epsilon$ for epsilon small enough in the case $K=[-1,1]$, am I correct?